# secure Oracle connection from java applet

Tags: java, oracle, vpn

I've written a java applet that connects to Oracle on a hosted server.  I have been testing it by connecting by VPN to my hosting service and connecting to the Oracle database.  I've done this so I don't have to expose the Oracle db to outside connections, but now I need to be able to connect to Oracle without being on the VPN.  Is there any way to set up a security certificate or something so that Oracle only accepts an outside connection from my java applet?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Applets can use JDBC, Oracle has written a whitepaper titled [SSL with Oracle JDBC Thin Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/pdf/wp-oracle-jdbc_thin_ssl_2007.pdf) (PDF).  I haven't looked it over, but I imagine it has instructions on configuring both Oracle and the [Oracle JDBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html) for SSL.